# global Angular CLI version (7.2.2) is greater than your local version

Tags: angular6

I am working on Angular 2 application and getting error while trying to create component using CLI.

### command

```
ng g c mycomponent
```

i have tried to re-install cli by doing following but it seems not really working

```
ng new my-project
cd my-project
ng g c my-component --m app
```

### error

```
Your global Angular CLI version (7.2.2) is greater than your local
version (6.0.8). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
Could not find an NgModule. Use the skip-import option to skip importing in NgModule.
```

### ng version check on visual studio code

[image]

### ng version check on cmd

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the whole project and then when creating the component cd into your app folder then type the following.

```
$ ng g c component name --module app
```

It will for sure create a component.